# Date conversion in node.js

Tags: node.js

In my node app i have to convert the following date

```
2016-06-03T18:30:00.000Z
```

into the following format:

```
2 Apr 2016
```

I searched a lot for this, but cant find a solution. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `moment.js`:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var formattedDate = moment('2016-06-03T18:30:00.000Z').format("D MMM YYYY");
console.log(formattedDate) // 3 Jun 2016
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `moment.js` or `date-format` plugin, which will surely save a lot of things like this.

```
npm install dateformat
```

Then you could require the dateformat:

```
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
```

Then bind the value:

```
var day=dateFormat(dateObj, "yyyy-mm-dd h:MM:ss");
```

https://github.com/felixge/node-dateformat